# hibernate projection unique list

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to use hibernate and projection to result a list that doesn't have duplicated element.

I have a class CurrEntityProfileBO, it has property entityId.

```
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(
                CurrEntityProfileBO.class, "entityProfileBO");
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections
    .projectionList().add(Projections.property("entityId"))));
```

I'm getting a exception:

```
[2014-11-04 11:28:59] ERROR [http-8080-5]      (SqlExceptionHelper.java:144) - ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

[2014-11-04 11:28:59]  WARN [http-8080-5] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:185) - Handler execution resulted in exception
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

at     org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
```

appreciated any helps!

Comment: What about `criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`?

Answer (score 0):

according to sp00m.
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
works very well!